# Program to write a given number in "dd Mon yyyy" date format

Tags: algorithm, date, language-agnostic

In one of my recent interview, the following question was asked.

> Given a number, write it in "dd Mon yyyy" date format. Sample input: n = 12122013; output: "12 Dec 2013". The date format can be ddmmyyyy, mmddyyyy and yyyymmdd.

In this problem, we have to deduce the input format. How do I differentiate between ddmmyyy and yyyymmdd formats? If the input is 23051018, then it could be either "23 May 1018" or "18 Oct 2305". Note: The method signature in Java is:

```
static String formatNumberToDate(int n)
```

EDIT:
If one can't differentiate among date formats, how should one approach this problem? This question was asked in a written exam.

Comment: Sorry, it is not tied to any programming language. The sample method signature was given as a reference by the interviewer. Candidates were free to write in programming language of their choice. Should I add Java, C and C++ tags?

Comment: There is the tag `language-agnostic`, if you don't want to specify a language. But you will get more answers, if you specify a language. Up to you.

Comment: You can't differentiate in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, you cannot know for sure. That number alone does not tell you unambiguously what format the date is. Take `01010101`: it can be interpreted either way.

Now that we got that out of the way, we can think about how the format could be passed. If the signature really must be just an `int` as a parameter, you could pass the format as an additional digit. Every format corresponds to one digit. Then parse that and choose the appropriate format.